# Can my S Corp pay my personal tax liability and can my S Corp be able to deduct the taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, business, s-corporation

I understand S Corps are flow through entities so if I am paying the net income on my personal taxes then can the S Corp pay for the taxes due?  Also can the S Corp be able to deduct the taxes paid as a deduction?

Answer (score 3):

> can the S Corp pay for the taxes due?

Why? Why would the corporation, a separate legal entity, pay your personal obligations? Do you want to pierce the corporate veil? Because that's how you pierce the corporate veil.

> Also can the S Corp be able to deduct the taxes paid as a deduction?

Of course not, how is it a deduction for the corporation? It's not a legitimate business expense.

The corporation can pay you a salary, and withhold taxes on your behalf from that salary. In fact, the corporation is *required* to do that if it's profitable (you're required to pay yourself a reasonable salary before taking distributions). But the corporation cannot and should not pay your personal obligations.

Comment: The corporation does pay me a salary and with withholdings I am entitled to a refund.  However when the corporations net income flows over to my personal then I now owe taxes.  The taxes due is from the corporation.  If the corp is able to pay and be able to deduct the annual $800 corp tax then I don't see how this is any different because it is a tax incurred by the corporation.

Comment: @Dallat it is not a tax incurred *by the corporation*. It is a tax incurred *by you* because you received net profit from the corporation, as the owner.